# How to use response object in kotlin

Tags: java, json, kotlin, object, response

it was to ask how I can access different JSON objects in kotlin (they are inside the response)

I'm a newbie, it was to ask what is the best way to handle response objects

```
  Fuel.post("usuario/login").jsonBody("{ \"email\" : \"cristian@admin.com\" , \"password\" : \"123456\"}")
        .response { request, response, result ->
        
           //println(response); // body:{token:34urfd9sf9dudu9sj}
           println(response.body.token) //error "token" doesn't exist

         
        }
```

This code is kotlin in android studio

in response I get several things, one of them is the "token" I thought that to access I only wrote response.token But it doesn't work :(

Comment: you'll  need to do : `response.body.token`, the intellisense should have helped you out on this...

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the `token` json object in order to access it's value.

Something like the following will work

```kotlin
println(JSONObject(response.body).get("token"))
```